# Using NancyFx as proxy

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, routes, nancy

Is there a way to use proxy concept with NancyFx? I mean, I would like to access a service and record the response in my Nancy application (as proxy), either on a JSON file ([similiar to wiremock](http://wiremock.org/docs/proxying/)) or in memory ([similar to mountebank](http://www.mbtest.org/docs/api/proxies))

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could certainly write a load of code to log the request and response, and use one of the standard web clients to pass the request back to the service, but Nancy has no built in system for this - Nancy is an MVC web framework, not a proxy server.

Perhaps you need something more along the lines of Nginx?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [WireMock.net](https://github.com/WireMock-Net/WireMock.Net) as it has a proxy feature and saves the results to json files.

Towards the end of this article is [an example of using the proxy feature of wiremock](https://alastaircrabtree.com/stubbing-your-way-to-automated-e2e-testing-api-first-with-wiremock/).